# Discard initiator and terminator from a column in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I want to remove the initiator (`[`) and terminator (`]`) from a column of input file while loading into Hive (or after loading into Hive).
The column contains an array of elements, for example: `['a','b','c','d','e']`

Answer (score 0):

Hive mostly work on delimited files (columns are separated by a delimiter), or other files which support serdes (json, regex, special csv etc).

So you can do this in either of the below approach:

1. Clean your data prior to loading in hive table to a delimited format.
2. Use regex serde to extract data correctly from pattern [digit,digit,..]